# How to replace the value of the text element in svg from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-edit

I am creating an svg tool for the constructing a building , i had created a room ( with the  rect tool ) and grouped it and now want to place the name for that room eg : "Office" for the first time the text placed inside the rect , but for the next time i have to replace the name already exit inside the text element .
Below is my code

```
    var svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';     
    var ex_x=70;
    var ex_y=30;

    var hidden = parseInt($("#svg_group_osiz_1").val());    
    var gethide_curtselid=$("#hide_curtselid").val();      
    var gethide_curtselid12=$("#hide_curtdrawx_id").val();     
    var gethide_curtselid13=$("#hide_curtdrawy_id").val();       

    var x=parseInt(gethide_curtselid12) + parseInt(ex_x);  
    var y=parseInt(gethide_curtselid13) + parseInt(ex_y);            

    var text = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'text');  

    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x); 
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);           
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#343938');    
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'text-anchor', 'middle');
    text.textContent =room_name;    

    var html =$( "#"+gethide_curtselid ).html();        

    if(html.contains("</text>"))
    {       
        var start_string=html.indexOf("<text");
        var end_string  =   html.indexOf("</text>");        
        end_string      =   end_string+7;   
        remove_string   =   html.substring(start_string,end_string);        
        var content_replaced = html.replace(remove_string,"");      

        $( "#"+gethide_curtselid ).html(content_replaced);
        var replaced_html =$( "#"+gethide_curtselid ).html();   

    }   

    $( "#"+gethide_curtselid ).append(text);
```

Here i had find whether the text is already present in the group and replace it as empty and again append the text, But it do-sent work. Can any one guide

Comment: `But it do-sent work` - _but it doesn't work_? (I'd type `I` in all capitals, just as `SVG`.)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting an id for the textNode

```
var text = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'text');  
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x); 
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);           
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#343938');    
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'text-anchor', 'middle');
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'roomName');
text.textContent =room_name;
```

Then you can manipulate it using js like

```
document.getElementById('roomName').textContent = "new text";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that you are having a problem with Internet Explorer.  This is because the **JQuery** **html()** method returns "undefined" when applied to `<text>` elements inside of an `<svg>` container.  **JQuery** **html()** will work in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.  Use **JQuery** **text()** method instead, it does not return the whole inner HTML of the element, just the text but that should not be an issue for text in an SVG.

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px">
<text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#AAA">Some text</text>
</svg>
```

Chrome:

```
> $("svg text").html()
"Some text"
```

IE11:

```
$("svg text").html()
undefined
```

This works on both Chrome and IE:

```
> $("svg text").text()
"Some text"
```

Answer (score -1):

You already use jQuery, take more advantage of it.

```
var ex_x=70;
var ex_y=30;

var hidden = parseInt($("#svg_group_osiz_1").val());    
var gethide_curtselid=$("#hide_curtselid").val();      
var gethide_curtselid12=$("#hide_curtdrawx_id").val();     
var gethide_curtselid13=$("#hide_curtdrawy_id").val();       

var x=parseInt(gethide_curtselid12) + parseInt(ex_x);  
var y=parseInt(gethide_curtselid13) + parseInt(ex_y);

// find existing text element
var $parent = $( "#"+gethide_curtselid );
var $text = $parent.find('text');

// if there is no <text>, create a <text> element with fixed value attributes
// and append it to $parent.
if ($text.length == 0) {
   $text = $('<text fill="#343938" text-anchor="middle" />').appendTo($parent);
}

// set attributes and text content.
$text.text( room_name ).attr( {x: x, y: y} );
```

Comment: This will not work.  SVG elements have a different namespace from HTML, and you can't use jQuery to create them like that.